# Running 3 monitors on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I would like to run 3 monitors on Ubuntu 12.04. I have NVIDIA Quadro 5000 which is able to support 2 monitors. I only have an additional PCI slot so my option are limited for a second graphics card. I bought NVIDIA GEForce 6200, but I am not able to get Quadro 5000 and GEForce 6200 working simultaneously since they require different drivers. NVIDIA does not let me have more than 1 NVIDIA driver at a time.

Does anyone have suggestions? I was also considering to use USB 2.0 to VGA connectors. Has anyone had success with that on Ubuntu? Would it work if I got a AMD graphics card instead of NVIDIA?

Thanks